# Gradient from svg to png not applied

Tags: java, svg

I had one `SVG` file, I changed it so it has a gradient.

Then I convert the `SVG` to `png`, but the gradient change is not in the new `png`.

I tried to convert `SVG` to `png` with an internet converter, but it still doesn't pass the gradient.

When I open `svg` file with Illustrator I cannot see the gradient. When the preview of the `SVG` file is shown I can see the gradient.

I get this `error: org.apache.batik.bridge.BridgeException The attribute d of the element <path> is invalid.`

My question is:

If anyone has faced a similar error or has an idea about how to fix this, could you give me some advice?

Here's my converter:

```
public void svgToPng() throws MalformedURLException {

    String svg= "/Users/userName/svg/";
    File folder = new File(svg);

    for (File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {

        String[] codigoAux = fileEntry.getName().split("\\.");

        if (codigoAux[0].isEmpty()) {

            LOGGER.debug("Name of file is empty");

        } else {
            try {

                PNGTranscoder transcoder = new PNGTranscoder();

                String svgURI = fileEntry.toURI().toURL().toString();
                TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(svgURI);

                String outputPath = "/Users/userName/png/";

                OutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(outputPath + codigoAux[0] + ".png");
                TranscoderOutput output = new TranscoderOutput(ostream);

                transcoder.transcode(input, output);

                ostream.flush();
                ostream.close();


            }catch (TranscoderException ex) {

                LOGGER.error(ex);

            } catch (IOException ex) {

                LOGGER.error(ex);

            }

        }


    }

}
```

Here's my element path in my svg:

```
<path fill="#D1E9FD" d="M7095.36-13.684c800.463,818.206,1299.013,1969.505,1299.013,3244.739             c0,633.732-123.293,1236.744-345.429,1783.602H305.852C83.733,4467.799-39.558,3864.79-39.558,3231.055             c0-1275.234,498.537-2426.534,1299.021-3244.739H7095.36z"></path>
```

Here's my gradient in my SVG:

```
<linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">        
    <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF;stop-opacity:1"></stop>        
    <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#FFE69C;stop-opacity:1"></stop>    
</linearGradient>
```

And here's where I make a reference to the gradient:

```
<style>        #Countries path, #Countries polygon {        
fill: url(#grad1);        filter: url(#dropshadow);        }    
</style>
```

I expect the output to be a PNG image with the gradient that I have in the preview of my SVG file.

Comment: The problem is with your SVG. But it's hard to tell what that problem is without seeing it. Can you post it?  The path you listed is valid. It should not be causing an error. Are you sure it is the correct one?

Comment: It's the correct one. I just edited the post with the lineargradient and style tags.

Comment: I see that your path also has a filter. If there is an issue with the filter, the path may not be displayed.  So we still don't have enough information to resolve this issue. Please create an [mcve]. Ie. post a cut-down version of your SVG that includes the path and all the resources it uses (gradient and filter).  Confirm that it works in a browser, but fails in Batik. Then update your question and include it.